# Choose correct return type of template member function

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, return-type

I have a template class that looks like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N> // MxN matrix with elements of type T
struct Mtx{...}

// component wise division
template <typename U> Mtx operator/(const Mtx<U, M, N> &rhs) const 
{ return componentDivide(*this, rhs); }
```

What is the best way to ensure that the return type of functions like `operator /` is "correct"?

eg:

```
Mtx<float> * Mtx<unsigned> = Mtx<float>
Mtx<float> * Mtx<int>      = Mtx<float>
Mtx<float> * Mtx<double>   = Mtx<double>
Mtx<double> * Mtx<float>   = Mtx<double>
Mtx<short> * Mtx<int>      = Mtx<int>
```

Comment: How about using [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)?

Comment: And if `std::common_type` does not (or does not always) provide the desired type, you could provide your own specializations.

Comment: This is what I am looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @aCuria: You can self-answer this question so that it can be useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally lean on the side of `decltype(std::declval<T>() / std::declval<U>())` rather than `std::common_type`, because it explicitly chooses the type to mirror an actual division.

Thus:

```
template <typename T>
struct Mtx 
{
    T _var;

    template <typename U> 
    Mtx<decltype(std::declval<T>() / std::declval<U>())>
    operator / (const Mtx<U> &rhs) const
    {
        return this->_var / rhs._var;
    }
};
```

Or, by using a trailing return type so we can express it with the parameters' types:

```
template <typename T>
struct Mtx 
{
    T _var;

    template <typename U> 
    auto operator / (const Mtx<U> &rhs) const
        -> Mtx<decltype(this->_var / rhs._var)>
    {
        return this->_var / rhs._var;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is this only useful for division? what does decltype(std::declval<T>() / std::declval<U>() actually do?

Comment: @aCuria It "simulates" dividing a value of type `T` by a value of type `U`, and looks at what type that would return. You can compose (almost) any expression inside `decltype` that way, so it works for all operators.

Comment: I see, this does make a difference for situations like short * short. std::common_type will output a short, while decltype will give you an int.

Comment: @Quentin But that makes the question, what **should be** (in real life) the common return type of a function which returns a `Mtx<short>`? I saw this change when I used trailing return type what you talked about. That's the reason why I did not add the soln.

Comment: @JeJo depends on whether you agree with the language on integer promotion :)

Comment: @Quentin One man standing against the standard community with only personal aspects; Hmmm... doesn't win the race. I agree.. Let it promoted to `int`. ;) On the other side, why not that promotion happened, in the case of `std::common_type`!!, komisch!! ;)

Comment: @JeJo to be fair integer promotions mimick those from C, and far from everyone involved consider them useful. I personally doubt thay'd be part of the language were it to be designed today, but I tend to adhere to coherency as a first default. Won't be mad if someone says "integer promotions are stupid and I won't use that" :)

Answer (score 3):

As @Someprogrammerdude mentioned in the comments using [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) should work for what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct Mtx 
{
    T _var;
    template <typename U> 
    Mtx<std::common_type_t<T, U>> operator/(const Mtx<U> &rhs) const
    {
        return this->_var/rhs._var;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Mtx<float> fObj{ 1.02f };
    Mtx<unsigned> uObj{ 1 };
    Mtx<int> iObj{ 1 };
    Mtx<double> dObj{ 1.02 };
    Mtx<short> sObj{ 1 };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_same_v< decltype(fObj / uObj), Mtx<float>> << '\n'  // Mtx<float> * Mtx<unsigned> = Mtx<float>
        << std::is_same_v< decltype(fObj / iObj), Mtx<float>> << '\n'  // Mtx<float> * Mtx<int> = Mtx<float>
        << std::is_same_v< decltype(fObj / dObj), Mtx<double>> << '\n' // Mtx<float> * Mtx<double> = Mtx<double>
        << std::is_same_v< decltype(dObj / fObj), Mtx<double>> << '\n' // Mtx<double> * Mtx<float> = Mtx<double>
        << std::is_same_v< decltype(sObj / iObj), Mtx<int>> << '\n';   // Mtx<short> * Mtx<int> = Mtx<int>
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
true
true
true
true
true
```

Comment: See [here an example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sfRiX3TnuMLnvjpj) code.